# go refspec: assignability of defined/undefined types

Tags: go

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability says:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V
>   or T is not a defined type.
> - ...

I have trouble testing this. Does "assignability" allow for casting (I guess yes)?
If so, why does
https://play.golang.org/p/Y-U5ruLH_bd
compile, even though *both* type_x and type_y are defined types?

If concept of assignability does not allow casting, why does
https://play.golang.org/p/dHDq9nnWSMC
NOT compile, even though int and type_x have same underlying types?

Comment: `x = type_x(y)`: `x` is of type `type_x`, `type_x(y)` is a conversion expression that results in a value of `type_x`. Assigning a value of `type_x` to a variable of type `type_x` should not be controversial. Why would you expect it to *not* compile?

Comment: `i = x`: both `int` and `type_x` are defined types, so that assignment violates the *`"and at least one of V or T is not a defined type."`* part of the quoted condition. An example to illustrate the defined/undefined difference: https://play.golang.org/p/fjmjZFkXzQY

Comment: Also keep in mind that there is *no* casting in Go. Conversion, yes, but casting, no.

Comment: @mkopriva then it looks like I don't understand what a "defined type" is. I thought a defined type must be defined using a "type" keyword, which int doesn't do?

Comment: A defined type is any type that has a name, e.g `int` is defined (defined in the package `builtin`), `[]int` isn’t defined (`[]` are not legal characters for an identifier so they can never be part of a *name*), `type intSlice []int` produces a defined type `intSlice`...

Comment: "Does "assignability" allow for casting (I guess yes)?" No, of course not as there _are_ _no_ type casts in Go.

Comment: @mkopriva thank you. Note for self: here it explicitly says int and other numeric types are defined: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types

Comment: @mkopriva undefined types are anonymous structs/interfaces only ? can it be something else ?

Comment: @mh-cbon yes struct and interface types, but also map, slice, array, channel, pointer, and function types can be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I believe https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions was what you were looking for.

In short, you are not assigning a value of type type_y to a variable of type type_x, but rather converting that value to one of type type_x before assigning it. The restrictions on conversions are a lot less tight.

Directly assigning the value of y to x will not be allowed by the compiler, for the reasons you linked to.